# Spring Jpa: Lazy fetching for ManyToOne

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have Record entity:

```
@Entity
public class Record implements Serializable {

   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
   private User user;
   ...
```

and corresponding RecordRepository repository:

```
public interface RecordRepository extends JpaRepository<Record, Integer> {

    List<Record> findByUser(User user); 
    ...
```

Whenever I call **findByUser** the resulted **records contains users**. But I would like to achieve that **users will not be fetched** from database (record.user == null).

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Why would you want that? Your code would be filled with bugs because it would assume that a record doesn't have a user whereas it actually has one. And saving the record would remove the association between the record and the user, because, well, since the user in the record is null, that means the record doesn't have a user. You do understand that the user inside the record is just an empty shell, that is lazily populated, only when you actually call methods on the user, right?

Comment: For the performance reason. I am sending list of records for particular user to the client and I don't need to have filled this user in each record.

Comment: It's not filled. It's just an empty shell. A proxy that will only load the user data if you call a method on the user. If you don't call any method on the user, then the user data is not loaded from the database. If you do call methods, then that means your code has a bug, since it's not supposed to load user data.

Comment: Well I think that as I am searching for record by user itself , that is the reason why user if fetched.

Comment: Indeed. But my guess is that you're asking the wrong question. What you want to do is send the information of records, without the information about their user, to a third-party application (the client). That is very, very different from not loading the user information of these records from the database, using Hibernate. The answer is in the communication layer, not in the persistence layer. Change what you send, or how you send it. Don't change try to change the way you load data from the database. In short, assuming you use Jackson to send JSON, you have a Jackson/DTO problem, not a JPA one

Comment: Yes, handling that on communication layer is my current solution. But I was just wondering if it is possible in Hibernate to prevent fetching data for such case when this data are just used in searching query.

Answer (score 0):

If the Records are fetching User objects together via this findByUser method, try to rewrite it so it uses just the ID instead:

```
public interface RecordRepository extends JpaRepository<Record, Integer> {
    List<Record> findByUserId(Long id);
}
```

This should not fetch the User for the Record until you touch it.

Now if you don't want to send the User to the output, you still have to ignore it on that side. E.g. using @JsonIgnore on the Record.getUser() method, or just don't map it in your DTO converter if you are using DTOs (which you should, if you have different representations of the same entity).